# How to get value from mMap in intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, data-retrieval

[image]

I have attached image.Please tell, how to retrieve values from mMap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access fields with in Object.
I want to access "displayValue".

```
Object o = data.getExtras().get("Barcode");
Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("displayValue");
f.setAccessible(true);
String value = (String) f.get(o);
```

One way to access the field with in Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your mMap only has one value so you can extract that value using:

```
  Barcode barcode = mMap.valueAt(0);
```

In other cases you can iterate over your mMap.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Issue is i can't not directly access to "mMap".
I have accessed object through this "data.getExtras().get("Barcode");"
Now how can i access to inner fields ?
I have got value[0].

Comment: @SHH, what inner fields do you need to access and why? Seems like you are on a wrong way, can you clarify your use-case?

Comment: "data.getExtras().get("Barcode");", Using the mention statement i am getting an object, object containing fields are mentioned in above picture in values array (i need to access array field i.e displayValue);